# Textbox value es borrado en la hacer submit

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

verán, tengo un formulario llamado "Guía" con varios campos , por necesidad operativa, el registro  de dicha guía es creado de manera automática para usar el ID, entonces al guardar siempre hace un UPDATE.

El problema viene unica y exclusivamente con un campo llamado "IValorDeclarado" que es un campo numérico, si yo accedo al formulario a modificarlo ya sea por ves primera o posteriormente, lo guarda correctamente. Pero si ingreso nuevamente y modifico cualquier otro campo o simplemente hago clic en el botón guardar para salir del formulario el valor llega en 0 al controller. He revisado todo el código y las funciones, en ningún lado lo modifico, incluso en mis scripts, entonces no se a que pueda deberse este bug, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GuardarGuia", "Operacion", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmGuia" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Guia.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClienteId)

            //Cliente
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Cliente:</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClienteNombre, new { @class = "form-control", ReadOnly = "ReadOnly" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            //No manifiesto, No guia, Fecha
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">No. guía:</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.NoFolio, new { @maxlength = "50", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">No. manifiesto:</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.ManifiestoId, new { @class = "form-control", ReadOnly = "ReadOnly" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Fecha:</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaGuia, "{0:D}", new { @class = "form-control", ReadOnly = "ReadOnly" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            


            <br />

            //Valor Declarado, Peso, Piezas, Volumen
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Valor declarado:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.IValorDeclarado,"{0:N2}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">MXN</span>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Peso:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.Peso, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">KG</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Piezas:</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.Piezas, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Volumen:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guia.Volumen, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control", @style = "cursor: pointer;" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("FormVolumen","Operacion", new { GuiaId = Model.Guia.Id })" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
                                </a>
                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <br />

            // Observaciones
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #f5f5fa; border-radius: 10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Observaciones:</label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Guia.Observacion, 5, 15, new { @maxlength = "500", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Atras", "TablaGuias", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                        <input type="submit" id="BtnGuardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

En mi controller, tengo lo siguiente para guardar:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GuardarGuia (FormGuia mdl)
        {
            if(ValidarStatusManifiesto(mdl.Guia.ManifiestoId) == true)
            {
                    AlbatrosCtx ctx = new AlbatrosCtx();

                    if (!ctx.GuiaDB.Any(dbo => dbo.Id != mdl.Guia.Id
                    && dbo.NoFolio == mdl.Guia.NoFolio
                    && dbo.Status == (byte)Guia.EStatus.Activo))
                    {
                        var GuiaUpdt = ctx.GuiaDB.SingleOrDefault(dbo => dbo.Id == mdl.Guia.Id);

                        GuiaUpdt.NoFolio = mdl.Guia.NoFolio;
                        GuiaUpdt.IValorDeclarado = mdl.Guia.IValorDeclarado;
                        GuiaUpdt.Piezas = mdl.Guia.Piezas;
                        GuiaUpdt.Peso = mdl.Guia.Peso;
                        GuiaUpdt.Observacion = mdl.Guia.Observacion;
                        GuiaUpdt.Status = (byte)Guia.EStatus.Activo;
                        GuiaUpdt.RUUsuarioId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UsuarioId"]);
                        GuiaUpdt.RUClienteId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ClienteId"]);
                        GuiaUpdt.RUFecha = DateTime.Now;

                        ctx.SaveChanges();

                        using (ctx)
                        {
                            foreach (var Ecarga in mdl.GuiaCarga)
                            {
                                GuiaCarga Carga = new GuiaCarga();

                                Carga = ctx.GuiaCargaDB.SingleOrDefault(dbo => dbo.Id == Ecarga.Id);
                                Carga.Cantidad = Ecarga.Cantidad;
                                Carga.Descripcion = Ecarga.Descripcion;

                                ctx.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }

                        GuiaFiltro Filtro = new GuiaFiltro();
                        Filtro.ManifiestoId = mdl.Guia.ManifiestoId;
                        Filtro.FechaInicial = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
                        Filtro.FechaFinal = DateTime.Now.Date;
                        Filtro.Status = (byte)Guia.EStatus.Activo;
                        Session["Filtro"] = Filtro;

                        MostrarMensaje(Mensaje.Tipo.Correcto, "Registro de guía guardado correctamente.");
                        return RedirectToAction("TablaGuias");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MostrarMensaje(Mensaje.Tipo.Alerta, "El folio de guía ingresado ya se encuentra registrado.");
                        mdl.ListaSitios = Catalogo.ListaSitios(mdl.ClienteId);

                        return View("FormGuia", mdl);
                    }                
            }
            else
            {
                GuiaFiltro Filtro = new GuiaFiltro();
                Filtro.ManifiestoId = mdl.Guia.ManifiestoId;
                Filtro.FechaInicial = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
                Filtro.FechaFinal = DateTime.Now.Date;
                Filtro.Status = (byte)Guia.EStatus.Activo;
                Session["Filtro"] = Filtro;

                MostrarMensaje(Mensaje.Tipo.Error, "Solo es posible modificar guías de manifiestos activos.");
                return  RedirectToAction("TablaGuias");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta resuelto, era algo demasiado simple y absurdo. Resulta que en mi model el campo "IvalorDeclarado" es un "decimal", entonces al traer la información al formulario, estaba poniendo un  string format ("{0:N2}"), lo cual estaba agregando una "," a las cantidades mayores o iguales a 1000, me imagino que el controller al recibir la información pensaba que se trataba de un "string" y al no poderlo convertir, establecía el valor a "0", la solución fue simplemente cambiar el string format a ("{0:F2}").

Por cosas como estas es que me pregunto si hubiera sido mejor idea estudiar administración xDDD

Comment: no. no es que pensaba que era string. La cultura de tu sistema tomaba la coma como separador decimal, y entonces arruinaba el numero..

Comment: Entiendo, ¿entonces también podría solucionarse realizando un cambio de cultura?

Comment: Seguramente... no soy experto, pero quisiera creer que si

Comment: Intentare hacerlo y te comento los resultados, muchas gracias :)